# How does ApplicationId in Build.Gradle affect my package

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Hello this is just a technical question.Would appreciate an answer

I uploaded an app this afternoon to the play store using the default com.example but I couldn't as I was told "Its Restricted" so I changed it in my build.gradle to com.fanalcrystal.blah.blah.

I wanna know if I should change my package name in each file to reflect my applicationId as it is over 8hrs and my app is not showing on the play store when viewed on mobile phone but shows on the web store

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files inside your project do not need to use the same namespace as you set for `applicationId` in `build.gradle`. The applicationId is just what Google uses to identify your app inside the Play Store.

However, `AndroidManifest.xml` has a tag called `manifest` and that tag has an attribute called `package`. Again, this doesn't have to match the other files, but it is used to reference resources inside those files. For example: `com.example.R` is the package that allows you to reference a view using `R.id.view_name`.

I imagine Google's reserved some applicationIds, and I bet these are names like com.example, com.google, com.android, etc.

There are a bunch of reasons that could prevent your app from showing up on your device:

1. The Play Store caches content, and that cache wont expire at the same time. Eight hours is unusual, but it's not uncommon for app pages accessed on different devices to update over a period of time.
2. More likely you've done something in your manifest that excludes your device from being able to install your app. You can limit devices by API versions, screen sizes, device architecture, and a bunch of other things. Check out the APK page in publisher part of the store to see if there are any devices excluded.

Hope that helps.